# Angular 4 apply attributes upon declaration to component template (do not render wrapping element)

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-template

Let's say I want to make a custom button. 
So I create a component

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: '[extended-button]',
  template: `<button (click)="onClick($event)"></button>`,
  styles: []
})
export class ExtendedButtonComponent {
  @Input() disabled: boolean;
}
```

And when I use an instance of this button I want the attibutes I type when declaring it in the HTML to apply to the button inside the template:

```html
<div extended-button class="some-nice-button"></div>
```

So the results of this would be:

```html
<button class="some-nice-button" (click)="onClick($event)"></button>
```

I really don't want the `<div>` tag to be rendered. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is what you want to achieve but see the code snippets below:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-button',
  template: `<button [class]="className" (click)="onClick($event)>Custom Button</button>`
})
export class CustomButtonComponent {
   @Input() className: string;
}
```

Then when you want to use this `custom-button`, you can attach it to another component like so:

```
<custom-button [className]="someClassName"></custom-button>
```

Then in the component ts file, you need to specify `someClassName`:

```
someClassName: string = 'someRandomClassName';
```

I hope this will help you.

EDIT: [image: How the custom button gets rendered]

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I'm not really looking for this. I really don't want any wrapping element to be rendered. I want the attributes I put when declaring the element in the html to apply to the button in the template. Maybe I should look into directives or something.

Comment: I've just read something about this couple of hours ago. What you really need is indeed Directives and Ng-template as ng-template does not get rendered. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you want to achieve but i think you should use your selector as a html tag, like this:

```
<div>
<extended-button></extended-button>
</div>
```